# Дана очередь. Как мне сделать так, что бы сначала высвечивались все элементы меньше 5, а потом остальные?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int a1;
    int q1[10];
    int start_1 = 0, ends_1 = 0;

    int c = 5;


    for (int h = 0; h < 10; h++) 
    {
        a1 = rand() % 10;
        q1[start_1++] = a1;
        //cout << a1 << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Только вместо очереди у Вас массив.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cout << "Mass: " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        cout << q1[i] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;
//Меньше
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {

            if (q1[i] < c)
            {
                cout << q1[i] << " ";
            } 
    }

    cout << endl;
//Больше
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
    if (q1[i] > c)
    {
        cout << q1[i] << " ";
    }

    }
```

Comment: А если равно? У вас тут недочет: общее количество элементов может быть больше, чем вы выводите на экран.